# Why is xargs not executing my shell script?

Tags: bash, xargs

I need to use drush (Drupal shell) to report on a long list of modules -- basically this is a one line shell script with a list of module names in a file. xargs should be able to do this but I cannot get it to work.

My shell script, drpm.sh, looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash
drush pm-releases $1
```

The first few lines of my input file look like:

```
admin_menu
advanced_help
aggregator
anonymous_contact
ldapauth
...
```

(BTW, the lines in the file are terminated by ^M, if that matters...)

But when I run the command:

```
xargs -0 -L 1 -a myfilename.txt ./drpm.sh
```

I get the result:

```
No release history was found for the requested project (admin_menu                                                                                                                      [warning]
).
No release history was found for the requested project (advanced_help                                                                                                                   [warning]
).
No release history was found for the requested project (aggregator                                                                                                                      [warning]
)....
```

But if I type `./drpm.sh admin_menu` I get:

```
------- RELEASES FOR 'ADMIN_MENU' PROJECT -------
 Release         Date         Status
 6.x-3.x-dev     2013-Sep-30  Development
 6.x-3.0-alpha4  2010-Mar-11  Supported
 6.x-1.x-dev     2013-Sep-30  Development
 6.x-1.8         2011-Jun-16  Supported, Recommended
```

which is the result I want to get for the entire list in my input file.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It seems the line endings of your file are a problem. Use newlines instead of carriage returns.

Comment: Thanks glenn jackman: that worked. The options for -0 -L 1 were required as well.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to look at your `xargs` manpage to see what the different parameters it can use. Gnu vs. BSD vs. System VII are all different.

However, on my Mac (BSD), the `-0` parameter says that file names are NULL separated and not white space separated. Yet, your names are whitespace separated. Get rid of the `-0` and it might work.

I also notice that you're using `-L 1` which calls your command once per entry. The whole purpose of `xargs` is to call the program as few times as possible. If you're going to call it once per project name anyway, just use a loop:

```
while read project
do
    ./drpm.sh $project
done < myfilename.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but when I run your example, I still get the same result as above...frustrating. But was not aware xargs differs by *nix platform, thanks.

Comment: Any chance that input file was created on Windows? If so, you may have `<CR><LF>` endings on the file. You can check the line endings with `vim` using `:set ff?` This will say "DOS" or "UNIX". You can set it by doing `:set ff=unix` and then saving the file again. If you actually see `^M`, you need to delete those from the end of each line. Also, make sure that the last line has a `<LF>` on the end. If you open the file and save it in VIM, it will have that `<LF>` on the end of the last line.

Answer (score 0):

Your input isn't separated by NUL (`\0`) characters (as separators), therefore `-0` parameter isn't needed for `xargs`.

So keep it simple:

```
xargs -L1 ./drpm.sh < myfilename.txt
```